ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.postprocessor'
I tried to import CohereRerank module from llama_index. But got a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'llama_index.postprocessor'.

please share your full code. Also, mention your versions.

Try importing it this way :
from llama_index.postprocessor.cohere_rerank import CohereRerank
Ensure you have the following installed in your env
%pip install -q cohere llama-index-postprocessor-cohere-rerank
if the error still persists try making a fresh install for llamaindex and retry, it will work.
